# Arrayadapter cannot resolve constructor: no suitable constructor found, actual and formal arguments differ in length

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-arrayadapter

I have searched everywhere, but cannot find a solution for my problem. I'm new to java and I'm trying to build an app, but for some reason I can't get past this problem. I get this error:

> Error:(68, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   ArrayAdapter(OneFragment,int,String[]) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is not
>   applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not
>   applicable (actual argument OneFragment cannot be converted to Context
>   by method invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (actual argument OneFragment cannot be converted to Context by method
>   invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable (actual
>   argument OneFragment cannot be converted to Context by method
>   invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable (actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length)

The code (OneFragment.java):

```
package memo.javahelps.com.hanzesoep;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    ListView list;
    String[] itemname = {
            "Kippensoep",
            "Tomatensoep",
            "Thaise Kippensoep"
    };

    Integer[] imgid = {
            R.mipmap.kippensoep,
            R.drawable.tomatensoep,
            R.drawable.thaisekip,
    };

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);

        list=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;



        /* op item klikken */


        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(OneFragment.this,
                R.layout.list_item, itemname);

        list.setAdapter(adapter2);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(OneFragment.this.getActivity(), Kippensoep.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;


                }

            }
        });

}


    }
```

I'm trying to get separate items in a listview clickable with arrayadapter. Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post CustomListAdapter code

Comment: You need a `Context` for the first argument in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor. Use `getActivity()` like you did for the `CustomListAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayAdapter` constructor most similar to your constructor invocation is `ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[])`, but it is not applicable since `actual argument OneFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion`.

Here

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(OneFragment.this,
            R.layout.list_item, itemname);
```

you are passing a `Fragment` instance to the `ArrayAdapter` where a `Context` is required. You should pass the enclosing `Activity` instead:

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item, itemname);
```

In addition, `return rootView;` should be the last statement in your `onCreateView` method. Otherwise, the code that follows it will be unreachable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that too already, but doesn't work either? It gives the errors 'unreachable statement' and 'missing return statement'

Comment: @EsmeraldavanDaalen You have other problems with your code. You have statements that follow the `return rootView;` statement, so they are unreachable.